# How to force floating blocks staying in the same row in css?

Tags: html, css

So this is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3c40tafe/1/

How can I make the icon, file name and description in the same row? Meanwhile the width of the icon and title needs to be fixed, and the description paragraph takes the full of the rest width.

My code:

```
<div class="item_row">
                    <div class="result_item_icon"><img src="img/logo/xmas_kitten.png"></div>
                    <div class="result_item_name">12 Kittens of Xmas</div>
                    <div class="search_result_description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
                </div>
```

css:

```
.result_item_icon{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
} 
.result_item_icon img{
    max-width:50px;
    max-height:50px;
}

.result_item_name{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    font-weight:700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float;left
}
.search_result_description{
    display:block;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use floating blocks if you don't want them to wrap. Sounds to me like you want table-like behavior:

```
.item_row {
    display:table;
}
.item_row > * {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
/* remove display:block; and float:left; from child elements */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3ambhr3a/

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/3c40tafe/19/.

UI:

```
<div class="item_row">
<div style="float: left;">
                <div class="result_item_icon"><img src="img/logo/xmas_kitten.png"></div>
                <div class="result_item_name">12 Kittens of Xmas</div>
            </div>
                <div class="search_result_description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .result_item_icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.result_item_icon img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.result_item_name {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.search_result_description {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.result_item_icon{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    max-width: 50px;
    width: 10%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
} 
.result_item_icon img{
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.result_item_name{
    display: inline-block;
    height:50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 25%;
    font-weight:700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
.search_result_description{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 65%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3c40tafe/26/

Added max width to each one and gave the width a percentage based on its container (of 100%).

Also changed blocks to inline-blocks